# Visual Studio 2013 Capitalization Rules

Tags: html, visual-studio-2013, angular, angular2-routing

I have been working on learning angular2 project by using the great blog post, [Cross-platform Single Page Applications with ASP.NET Core 1.0, Angular 2 & TypeScript](http://chsakell.com/2015/12/31/cross-platform-single-page-applications-with-asp-net-5-angular-2-typescript/).

I created my app.html file with the following HTML

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/Home']"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;Photo Gallery</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I highlight the code and choose format selection the code get formatted to the following.

```
     <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" [routerlink]="['/Home']"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;Photo Gallery</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you can see the routerLink attribute has been formatted to be all lowercase which breaks the angular2 routing.  I have also seen this happen when I save a file, the html get auto formatted.

I have tried setting the properties in Tools-> Options->Text Editor -> Html (Web Forms) -> Formatting and change all of the Capitalization settings to "As Entered" but this did not fix my issue.